# My app deploys to Chrome but is rendered blank on other browsers/mobile phones

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, cross-browser, webkit

I have a react app that is deployed on heroku, (you can take a look [here](https://moodverse.netlify.app/)). But when I go there on Internet Explorer, microsoft edge, chrome app on my phone, safari app on my phone- it always renders a blank page.

A common issue I saw was with using redux-dev tools but I am not using redux in my app.

In my app I am using the Speech Recognition Web API and I know it is not cross browser compatible but it should work in Microsoft Edge at least. In my react app, I removed the component that was using the Speech Recognition API and deployed in on different domain to see if that was causing the issue. And now that deployment is also rendering a blank page on Chrome, (you can take a look [here](https://keen-bose-cb7159.netlify.app/)). I don't know what exactly that means and what is going on so if anybody could help me out even a little bit that would be much appreciated! My github repo is here [github](https://github.com/junaama/Mood-Verse)

Comment: In my chrome browser, it's blank as well

Comment: Your root element is simply just empty `<div id="root"></div>`. Console reports error and link: https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=301... looks like you have some infinite render looping, likely a bad/unguarded state update.

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks! I think I figured out the problem, I had a useEffect hook that was going off